# How to detect which activity has been selected and how to check if message has been sent?

Tags: ios, cocoa, touch, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've got code for simple sharing some messages from app.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithActivityItems:@[message]
                                                    applicationActivities:nil];

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Questions:

1. It is possible to detect which sharing option has been selected?
2. It is possible to detect if message was shared or canceled before?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So you asked a question, got the answer that allowed you to solve the problem, then added your own answer with some code, then decided to select your answer as the "correct" one? Hmmm just never saw that before. You cannot award yourself points, but decided the few points that SO awards should go to no one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a sample of how to use `UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler`:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]
                                                    initWithActivityItems:@[@"abc", someImage]
                                                    applicationActivities:nil];

[activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    NSLog(@"%@, %d", activityType, completed);
}];

activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: This is no longer viable for iOS 8 (as of beta 5), the `completionHandler` property is deprecated.

Comment: UIAcitivityViewController has a new completionWithItemsHandler property that is not in the docs, but is in the API diffs, and is defined in UIActivityViewController.h.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS8, the completionHandler property is deprecated.  Use the completionWithItemsHandler property instead:

```
activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray *returnedItems, NSError *activityError) {
NSLog(@"completed    = '%@'", (completed) ? @"YES" : @"NO");
NSLog(@"activityType = '%@'", activityType);
};
```

Comment: Excellent, it works, but were does it come from? It's not in the documentation...

Comment: @Guy: it is defined in UIActivityViewController.h.  I filed a Radar report with Apple to have it added to the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement the `UIActivityViewControllerCompletionHandler`, where you can see what the user did or if they canceled.